# How do you check the state of 9 pressed buttons in an if statement in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to check that state of 9 push button in my android application. If the buttons are all pressed it will return a dialog stating all button have been pushed/selected. Something like

```
if(buttonOne.isPressed() && buttonTwo.isPressed()){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You could have a counter and when ever the button is selected it +1's the counter, and if a button is deselected it -1's the counter. And check if the `counter == 9`...

Comment: Toggle button? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the button references in an array:

```
private Button[] buttonArray = new Button[]{button1, button2, ..., button9};
```

And then iterate over it as such

```
public boolean allButtonsPressed(){

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; ++i){

        if(!buttonArray[i].isPressed()) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
if(allButtonsPressed()){

   //show dialog
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the outlined idea but each time i attempt to click a button after running the application it crashes unexpectedly.

Comment: I guessed the types and methods etc, so just use the semantics from my answer and substitute in your variables, types, methods etc. Make sure your buttons are initialized when you reference them, otherwise you will get NullPointerExceptions. If that doesnt help, post your error message